# Why do I get error message on wikipedia api?

Tags: ajax, api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Can someone tell me what is wrong this code?

```
    $.ajax({
  "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
  "dataType": "jsonp",
    "action": "opensearch",
    "format": "json",
    "search": "new york",
    "namespace": "0",
    "limit": "3",
    "formatversion": "1",

  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Why do I get the following error message?

Refused to execute script from 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&callback=jQuery111105448874468459555_1518288921946&_=1518288921947' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Thank you.

Comment: You should remove the ? in your url. Also you might want to have a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/ja3qg73t/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are not [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) parameters (instead they are api parameters):

```
"action": "opensearch",
"format": "json",
"search": "new york",
"namespace": "0",
"limit": "3",
"formatversion": "1",
```

You can pass those values as query string, changing your url from:

```
"url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
```

to:

```
"url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?"+ $.param(apiParams),
```

where the api parameter is:

```
var apiParams = {action: 'opensearch', search: 'new york', limit: 3, namespace: 0, formatversion: 1, format: 'json'};
```

or you can use the data parameter like:

```
data: apiParams,
```

The snippet:

```js
var apiParams = {action: 'opensearch', search: 'new york', limit: 3, namespace: 0, formatversion: 1, format: 'json'};
$.ajax({
    "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?" + $.param(apiParams),
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    //data: apiParams,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```